# Add an NSDictionary to image metadata

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, assetslibrary

I'm trying to save an image with some custom metadata to a Photo Album. The custom metadata I would like to save should be in the form of a NSDictionary. Until now I have only succeeded in inserting an NSArray into the image metadata by using something like below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[metadata setObject:@[@"ele1", @"ele2"] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords];
NSMutableDictionary *meta = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[meta setObject:metadata forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary];
// pass the meta dictionary into writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

But what I would like is to pass a dictionary into setObject.
Has anyone succeeded in inserting a custom metadata into an image where the metadata is an NSDIctionary?

**Additional information**

I'm using the code I found here [Save CUSTOM metadata in an image taken from AVFoundation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8937963/1431713), to add a dictionary to the image metadata but still no luck. The original file is in the temporary directory and the final file is created via *writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum*. Like in the link, the resulting image doesn't contain the dictionary. Any idea?

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)data, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = [(NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL)autorelease];
NSMutableDictionary *metadataAsMutable = [metadata mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *RAWDictionary = [[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyRawDictionary]mutableCopy];

if(!RAWDictionary) {
    RAWDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

[RAWDictionary setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
[RAWDictionary setValue:@"value2" forKey:@"key2"];

[metadataAsMutable setObject:RAWDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyRawDictionary];

NSMutableData *newData = [NSMutableData data];

CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(source); 
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((CFMutableDataRef)newData, UTI, 1, NULL);

if(!destination) {
    NSLog(@"***Could not create image destination ***");
}

CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination,source,0, (CFDictionaryRef)metadataAsMutable);
BOOL success = NO;
success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);

if(!success) {
    NSLog(@"***Could not create data from image destination ***");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//covert image to nsdata format
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"your image path"];
NSMutableDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[metadata setObject:imageData forKey:@"imageData"];
```

Comment: Thanks..but it didn't work. I added some additional infos to my original question.

Comment: @Glauco what is mean didn't work ?? could you try to archived your data?? just like NSData *data = [NSKeyeArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:"your data"];

Comment: My idea was to add the metadata into the image. The merged image is then stored via ALAssetLibrary into a photo album. Then, at a later time, ALAssetLibrary to retrieve the images in the album. It's at this point I would like to retrieve the custom metadata stored at the beginning. I'm not sure how NSKeyeArchiver would help me. Do you have an example? or could you provide more information?